# Fatal error on OpenShift while connecting to github

Tags: github, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I'm new to OpenShift, all I'm trying is to build a sample app, trying .Net core. Created a new project then selected .Net core example. Now when I build it, it throws this error:

> Cloning "https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore-ex.git"...
>   error: fatal unable to access
>   'https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore-ex.git/': could
>   not resolve host: GitHub.com; Unknown error

I have not changed any config before build and no credentials needed. And I'm not using the OpenShift console.

Comment: What is the OpenShift cluster you are using? One you have set up, your companies, Minishift? Does this happen every time? So if you trigger a new build, does it always occur?

Comment: Can you access GitHub normally from where you are? My hunch is that it has nothing to do with OpenShift but rather either some firewall issue with GitHub or they might have some issues. Once we've established it's not GitHub, we can focus on OpenShift ;)

Comment: @michael, yes I can access github.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes face this issue everything I try to access a repo even with private github

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas yes I can access github repos open source and private

Comment: What does the following command give you? kubectl run -i -t --rm jumpod --restart=Never --image=quay.io/mhausenblas/jump:0.2 -- curl github.com

Comment: Can you answer the questions. What is the OpenShift cluster you are using? One you have set up, your companies, Minishift? If you setup the cluster yourself, or is company cluster, the DNS configuration when setup could have been wrong, resulting in DNS not working in pods. If Minishift, it could be because DNS port already in use, or firewall config not done properly.

Comment: The command Michael gave you should indicate whether DNS resolution is working in any type of pod. A build is just one type of pod.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton it's a company setup openshift and I believe everything has done by the company. Apologize could not run the command as yet to install the cli. Unfortunate due to office restrictions to install software. Let me get things install